# ASP.NET Identity cookie is missing on Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, firefox

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application, that contains both MVC and API controllers. I am migrating the sign-up part of the project from ASP.NET to React, so at the end of the process, the user should be redirected to an ASP.NET page. The user gets a JWT at some point during the signup process; at the end, there is an endpoint that takes the token, extracts the user id and signs the user in using the SignInManager.

Now, this works great on Chrome, but returns a 401 of Firefox. I used Fiddler to look into the requests, and it seems that for Firefox, the `AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie is missing. Since this is handled server-side, I assume it's something about how Firefox manages cookies.

Any ideas on how to have the cookie rolling on all browsers?

Comment: Are all cookies enabled in firefox?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing blocked. The same cookie is there when logging in normally from the ASP.NET website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the identity cookie can't be transferred from one domain to another on Firefox. After deploying the React project on the same domain, it works perfectly.